# How does DeepLink communication work in Facebook sparkar?

Tags: javascript, facebook, instagram, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

So I look into this [sample](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/deeplinkmodule/) and can not get two things:

- How And when request you external app Is made?
- Where are the external app deep link addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spark AR studio](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/download/) is an augmented reality design tool created for use with Instagram and Facebook (at present) but they have/ or had plans to use it with other Facebook apps like messenger and Facebook camera.

Intro videos here: https://developers.facebook.com/videos/2018/spark-ar-introduction-to-ar-studio/

Instagram does not allow you to use Deeplinks on its platform, it is intended to be used with the Facebook SDK only. When you create a Facebook app or Ad with a link, or your own Android or IOS app and use the Facebook SDK, you would be able to create and use Deeplinks within their ecosystem.

**So to answer your first question:** It is Facebook apps, ads and apps which use the Facebook SDK that can send parameters to you Spark AR effect. It is also these types of apps that Spark AR is talking about when they state:

> DeepLinkModule
>
> The DeepLinkModule class exposes methods and properties
> to read the values that an external app sent to an effect.

**The answer to your second point is:** In the Facebook Developer Dashboard, where you register and get app ID's for all your Facebook apps.

You can read more about Facebook Deeplinks and their construction here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/deep-linking/

Comment: So... is there any way my Instagram mask ar filter can access my app parameters using deep-link? (When user is using my filter and my app is also installed on the phone)

Comment: No. The filter will be run on Instagram, and they don't allow you to pass parameters from your app - to them - and then your filter.